# Handling composite widget's events

Tags: gwt, widget, composite, uibinder

I'm creating a composite widget using UiBinder. The widget is a login form, so basicly it has labels, textboxes and a button. I'm planning to use this widget within a view which is also declared using UiBinder. So, basicly I've got these files: LoginForm.ui.xml, LoginForm.java, MainViewImpl.ui.xml and MainViewImpl.java.

I'd have to define the event handlers of the login form in LoginForm.java using the @UiHandler annotation, however I'd like to know if there is a way to define those event handlers in MainView.java. Is that possible?

Comment: So basically you want to create a dependency of LoginForm.ui.xml to MainView.java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. That would break the *component* design pattern.

What you'd have to do is *expose* events on your `LoginForm` component that the `MainViewImpl` will be able to listen.

If it's a "one shot" though, I wouldn't bother creating events and instead simply use a *callback* interface that `MainViewImpl` implements and passes to `LoginForm` for it to call it back.
This is similar to the `Presenter` interface called back by the view in the [MVP – Part II article](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture-2.html) to notify the presenter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Thomas. I'll go with exposing events since it seems more straightforward to me.